# Which version of Hibernate tools file i should use to generate hibernate POJO for java 5

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, jboss-tools

It could be a silly question and i am sorry for that.

I am using ant task for generating POJO and hbm file from databse by using hybernate reverse engg.

But that is generated as per java 4 standard for eg.

```
private Set volunteerPhysicalInfos = new HashSet(0);

private Set volunteerReferences = new HashSet(0);
```

i am using **JBoss Tools 3.1 :: Eclipse 3.5.2** from 
http://www.jboss.org/tools/download

i want to generate the POJO files in java 5 standards for eg.

```
HashSet <String>collection = new HashSet <String>();
```

For this which version of hibernate tool i should use?

Answer (score 2):

got the answer
need to set jdk5="true"